# Change statusbar color for each screen

Tags: flutter, statusbar

I want to set status bar color for each screen.
E.g. in screen A status bar color is red and  in screen B is blue.
I tried many solutions. But each one has it's own problem.
like:

```
AnnotatedRegion(
    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: navigationBarColor,
        statusBarColor: statusBarColor,
    ),
    child: child,
);
```

or this before return in build method:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white
));
```

My final try :

```
  static void pushNamed({
    BuildContext context,
    String route,
    Object arguments,
    Color statusBarColor,
    Color navigationBarColor = Colors.black,
  }) async {
    if (statusBarColor != null) {
      await FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(statusBarColor);
    }
    await Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      route,
      arguments: arguments,
    );
  }
```

but sometimes fails.
and other problem of this solution is when use back button, color not changed.(I write my code for back button in appbar).
and even when in hot reload color change to previous.
How can I handle this problem?

**Update #2**

I create a class for my routing.

```
static void pushNamedAndRemoveUntil({
    BuildContext context,
    String route,
    Object arguments,
    Color statusBarColor,
    Color popStatucBarColor,
    Color popNavigationBarColor,
    Color navigationBarColor,
}) async {
    changeSystemColor(statusBarColor, navigationBarColor);
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        route,
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
        arguments: arguments,
    ).then((res) {
        changeSystemColor(popStatucBarColor, popNavigationBarColor);
    });
}
```

and:

```
void changeSystemColor(Color statusBarColor, Color navigationBarColor) {
  if (statusBarColor != null)
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: navigationBarColor ?? Colors.black,
        statusBarColor: statusBarColor,
      ),
    );
}
```

and for using this

```
Routing.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
    context: context,
    route: Routes.homeScreen,
    arguments: user,
    statusBarColor: Colors.teal,
);
```

and now not work when use pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.

Comment: @Eugene some screens doesn't have appbar and also when using appbar, status bar color is darker than appbar color.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @SumitShukla I post my workaround. It's not maybe best solution be works most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trigger the System Color change on initState or any of the other Stateful Widget lifecycle methods. The best way seems to be by setting the color before navigating to the new view and when return from that view:

```
void goToWhiteView(){
  changeSystemColor(Colors.white);
  Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    route,
    arguments: arguments,
  ).then((result){
    changeSystemColor(Colors.blue);
  });
}

void changeSystemColor(Color color){
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: color,
    statusBarColor: color
  ));
}
```

Comment: It check it but it sometimes fails and color stay same as previous screen.

Comment: Can you share how you've implemented it?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use an AppBar but set its height and elevation to 0 so that it only covers the status bar and has no shadow.</strike>

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
                child: new AppBar(
                        brightness: Brightness.light,
                        backgroundColor: backgroundColour,
                        elevation: 0,
                )
),
```

Then in `initState()` you can make the status bar transparent so it won't be discoloured.

You need to call this before and after your `await Navigator.push()` calls.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
   statusBarColor: desiredColour
));
```

Comment: It Doesn't work! color is from first screen with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I create ScreenContainer widget and wrap my screen with it:

```
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: statusbarcolor ?? ColorPalette.accent,
        statusBarIconBrightness: statusBarIconBrightness ?? Brightness.light,
      ),
      child: child,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  [focus_detector](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/focus_detector) for the page you want to set statusBarColor.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
    FocusDetector(
      onVisibilityGained: () {
        //Here you can change statusBarColor as you like
        SystemUiOverlayStyle systemUiOverlayStyle = SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark
        .copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent);
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(systemUiOverlayStyle);
      },
      child: YourOwnPage(),
    );
```

More information can see at [visibility_detector](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/visibility_detector).